# android target 16 needed when 18, 15, and 8 already downloaded?

Tags: android, eclipse, target

I have imported a project with these settings :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

and I had already downloaded the packages 18 , 15 and 8.

There is an error saying : "unable to resolve target 16" , would you know why? Is there somewhere else an option that would say "API 16 needed" ? And isn't it enough to have already the 3 packages ?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just download all the sdk?

Comment: @ObieMD5 I thought downloading the newest API was enough, and would be faster for Eclipse to start without all the APIs inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is an error saying : "unable to resolve target 16" , would you know why?

The build target of the project (e.g., Project > Properties > Android) was set to API Level 16. Eclipse should have automatically changed it to 18, given your described setup (first available higher SDK).

Comment: OK, that is what I thought, but I had to download the API 16, maybe I will understand the problem later on. thanks